# How to use source maps with basic authentication?

Tags: javascript, authentication

I want to use [Mirador](http://projectmirador.org/), an [IIIF](http://iiif.io) viewer on a site with [basic authentication](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Authentication).

The problem is that I receive the following error in the console:

> Source map error: request failed with status 401 Resource URL:
>   https://example.com/mirador/mirador.js Source Map URL:
>   openseadragon.js.map

Firefox is trying to get a source map (a way to map a combined/minified file back to an unbuilt state) but is not using the basic authentication credentials.

Answer (score 3):

Since this bug in Firefox still exists, here's what I found:

In Firefox, a workaround is to right-click-> Show page source. This should result in a new authorization request where you can re-enter the credentials. Then, reload the non-source (rendered) page again, and hopefully the 401 warning disappears.

In my case, the .map files for the .css files were not being loaded. After loading the source for the page, I was asked for the credentials again. In the Style Editor tab in the development tools, the source .less files started loading. It appears Firefox treats the loading of .map files similarly to the loading of the source for the page, and this is different from the loading of the rendered version of the page.

Comment: I can confirm that your solution works on Mozilla Firefox for Linux Mint, 86.0.1 (64-bit).

Answer (score 0):

The problem comes from a known Firefox bug:

[Bug 1404245 : Source map requests don't use stored HTTP basic auth credentials](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1404245)

There is at least three solutions:

1. Set `sourceMap: false` in `Gruntfile.js` and run `grunt`. This will generate a new `mirador.min.js` file without the sourceMap comment of the form:

   ```
   //# sourceMappingURL=http://example.com/path/to/your/sourcemap.map
   ```

   Source map will then be disabled on server side.
2. In Firefox, to go to Developer Tools -> Toolbox Options -> Advanced Settings and to uncheck `Enable Source Maps`. Source map will then be disabled on client side.
3. Wait for a bug fix.